# How do I autofill formulas horizontally in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created a google form that populates the values into an excel sheet. I want these values to be repopulated into another sheet within the same workbook where averages are calculated.

I want to autofill the cells with a formula by dragging the handle across without manual input, so it appears like so:

```
A1=Responses!B2; 
B1=Responses!C2; 
C1=Responses!D2;
D1==Responses!B3;
E1=Responses!C3;
F1=Responses!D3;
G1=Responses!B4;
H1=Responses!C4;
I1=Responses!D4

A2=Responses!B5
B2=Responses!C5
C2=Responses!D5
D2=Responses!B6
E2=Responses!C6
F2=Responses!D6
G2=Responses!B7
H2=Responses!C7
I2=Responses!D7
```

When I drag the cells across, it appears like so instead:

```
A1=Responses!B2; 
B1=Responses!C2; 
C1=Responses!D2;
D1==Responses!F2;
E1=Responses!G2;
F1=Responses!H2;
G1=Responses!I2;
H1=Responses!C4;
I1=Responses!D4
```

Comment: What you say is happening doesn't make sense if it is simple cell references.  You need to include your actual formula in order for people to figure out what's happening.

Comment: When I put my hand into the bag of jellybeans, I want one red, one orange, one yellow. Instead I get one green, one white, one purple. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Index with INT and MOD:

```
=INDEX(Responses!$B:$D,INT((COLUMN(A:A)-1)/3)+2+((ROW(1:1)-1)*3),MOD(COLUMN(A:A)-1,3)+1)
```

Put in A1 drag/copy to I1 and then down to include all the data desired.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @fixer1234 Fixed.

Comment: you totally fixed it! Thanks! However just a small problem, the original formula is =ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(LEFT(Responses!C2,1))). How do I include (VALUE(LEFT)) into your formula so it only picks the number value. e.g. the cell shows up as 4(awesome), but I only want it to reference '4' .

Comment: That was not a spec of the question.  But you would simply wrap the whole formula in `VALUE(LEFT(...,1))` where `...` is the formula above.  Remember to mark as correct if it worked,by clicking on the check mark by the answer, @auhcj

Comment: Sorry about this but how do I carry on the formula to the next worksheet? when I copy the last formula from the first worksheet onto the 2nd worksheet & drag it across, it reverts to the first original formula. e.g

Comment: E.G. if the last column on worksheet 1 shows

Comment: =VALUE(LEFT(INDEX(Responses!$B:$D,INT((COLUMN(AS:AS)-1)/3)+2+((ROW(7:7)-1)*3),MOD(COLUMN(AS:AS)-1,3)+1),1))

Is it correct if the first column on worksheet 2 shows

=VALUE(LEFT(INDEX(Responses!$B:$D,INT((COLUMN(AT:AT)-1)/3)+2+((ROW(7:7)-1)*3),MOD(COLUMN(AT:AT)-1,3)+1),1))

Comment: used the wrong desciptor, please replace the word column with cell.

Comment: The references that are relative will change if copying and pasting from one cell to the other.  To make them stay you need to copy the formula from the formula bar and not the entire cell.